# Увеличение разряда

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как без цикла дописать к `int` числу `n` нулей, т.е. увеличить разряд?

Comment: Умножение вам поможет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов как?

Comment: Как в школе учили: на сколько надо умножить число 5, чтобы к нему дописались два ноля?

Comment: число*pow(10,N) т.е. на 10 в степени N

Comment: pow работает с циклом

Comment: + нужно доп либу подключать

Comment: @pumpkin_bumpkin Я согласен, что приведенный ответ будет очень быстрым. И на счет лишней библиотеки соглашусь. И еще добавлю, что привлекать double для целочисленной арифметики как то перебор. НО почему вы считаете, что pow из математической библиотеки использует циклы ? Я в гугле сходу нашел несколько алгоритмов pow из примерно десятка инструкций процессора с плавающей точкой, без единого цикла.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сделайте таблицу с множителями, умножайте на множитель из таблицы.

```
const int table[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ... и так далее};
x *= table[n]; // "добавляем n нулей"
```

Comment: Вот, это нормальное решение, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без циклов, и без массивов.
Поскольку больше девяти нулей в формате int дописывать не надо, можно разложить множитель в произведение величин 10, 100, 10000, 1000000000. При этом коэффициенты соответствуют битам числа n:

```
x*=(n&1?10:1)*(n&2?100:1)*(n&4?10000:1)*(n&8?100000000:1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно использовать рекурсию. Вот такая функция

```
int power(int n) {     
    return n==0?1:10*power(n-1);
}
```

Допустим, нам нужно к числу k добавить n нулей:

```
k*power(n);
```